# Arduino code works on Visual Studio?

Tags: arduino

Right now, I'm working on Arduino IDE software to do Sensors Network project.

So, my question is:

I want to move all the code from Arduino IDE and use it in the Visual Studio?

It is impossible to make it work correctly!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/069a905d-387d-4415-bc37-665a5ac9caba) for VS you can install from the Visual Studio gallery. When I tried it it worked fine the first time but then some settings got lost (COM port number) and I could not get it fixed. It could be just my machine though...